# CKEditor plugin - How to fire DialogCommand in a proper way

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Previously, by clicking a toolbar button, I will launch my custom dialog immediately.

```
editor.addCommand('launch', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('myLaunchDialog'));
```

However, now, I wish to

1. Perform network activity first when toolbar button is clicked.
2. Upon completion of network activity, launch the custom dialog.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
editor.addCommand('launch', {
    exec : function( editor ) {
        performNetworkActivity(function() {
            // Network activity done!

            var command = new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('myLaunchDialog');
            // Hem... doesn't work
            editor.execCommand(command);
        });
    }},
    async : false
});
```

Note, `execCommand` doesn't work for me.

```
var command = new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('myLaunchDialog');
// Hem... doesn't work
editor.execCommand(command);
```

I even tried

```
var command = new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('myLaunchDialog');
command.enable();
command.exec();
```

Doesn't work still...

May I know what is the proper way to launch custom dialog programmatic-ally?

My dialog is defined as

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('myLaunchDialog', function( editor ) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proper way to fire dialog command.

```
var command = new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('myLaunchDialog');
editor.addCommand('_myLaunchDialog', command);

editor.addCommand('launch', {
    exec : function( editor ) {
        performNetworkActivity(function() {
            // Network activity done!

            editor.execCommand("_myLaunchDialog");
        });
    }},
    async : false
});
```